# Android Developer Guide/Android Studio reports wrong min API level

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've been using Android Studio for a while now, and it always reported the correct API level for the methods I use, and so did the Android Developer guide.

Then I encoutered the method View.setForeground(Drawable), introduced in Android M. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setForeground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) reports that it's on Android since API level 1, but that's wrong.

My question is: why? And, from now on, how can I verify that the API level that Android Studio/Android Developer Guide reports is right?

**EDIT**: issue reported to Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186273&thanks=186273&ts=1442226130

Comment: testing your app on older versions. There isn't much you can do, imo

Comment: if you are using a method with min level > your minSdk, Android Studio displays an error.

Comment: "My question is: why?" -- [It's a bug in the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3108). These things happen. In this specific case, it would not shock me if the method has existed since API Level 1, but was marked with `@hide` until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know with 100% certainty would be to manually check the file history for the file in question on [github](https://github.com/android), and double check the method you're looking at exists in the file revisions it is supposed to. This is not a realistic thing to do for every single method call, but if the developer documents are wrong there's no other way.

If you do notice errors such as this, you should check [the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) to see if the issue has been reported, and if not create a new issue so they can fix it. At least then you might save a few people from falling into the same trap.